# symfony displaying my form as select tag

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, twig

I am searching how to display all my attributes of my form that way:

For example in my entity class I have these attributes:

```
$number
$firstname
$lastname
$gender
```

And I want to display it like that instead of a classic form:

```
<select>
  <option value='number'>customized name</option>
  <option value='firstname'>customized name</option>
  <option value='lastname'>customized name</option>
  <option value='gender'>customized name</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="text"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

I searched if somebody already asked this and could not find anything.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

I am trying to do something like this:

```
$builder
            ->add('choices' => array('number' => 'Personel Number',
                                    'firstname' => 'First Name',
                                    'lastname' => 'Last Name',)
                'required' => true,
            ))
            ->add('Search',             'submit')
```

Comment: Have you looked at [the official docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-choices)? Create a custom form type, pass some options, use the formbuilder and add properties manually... the choice is yours, really

Answer (score 1):

It is, as you suggested, solvable with a choice entity field, however you need just a little bit more logic.
I am assuming you're building the form inside a Form Type.

```php
$choiceKeys = array_keys($options['data']); // where $options['data'] is your entity object! The form type automatically sets this variable
foreach ($choiceKeys as $key) {
    $choiceList[$key] = $some_translator->trans($key); // this should be the easiest way to get your fields translated like you want.
}

$builder->add('fieldName', 'choice', [
  'choices' => $choiceList
])
```

this snippet will result in a choice field containing all your entity fields in the choice list.
However this approach is a bit sloppy, and I'm sure you can find an architectural alternative in which you don't populate a choice field with your entity fields.. It smells like trouble to do so.
Anyway, if you need further help with this, please let me know!

Comment: An entity field _extends_ the choice field (see the link in my comment below the question). You _can_ have symfony render an entity as a choice (select) element easily, without having to use events to map the data back onto the entity in the first place

Comment: Elias, the entity field is used when you have a relation between two entities, and renders the target entity BY A SINGLE FIELD/__toString() method. You are completely right in your affirmation, however IMO this is not what @Hewyn is trying to achieve.

Comment: The entity _field_ is a form type, which extends the _choice_ type, all the way up to the generic _form_ type. You can still render it any way you like. Seeing as the OP wants to populate the choice field using data from an entity, it seems to me to be only natural to exploit the fact that you have an entity that provides said data. PS: `__toString` is not quite how entities are processed in symfony forms, check the source

Answer (score 0):

From symfony 2 documentation you should use in the following mode:

```
$builder->add('foo_choices', 'choice', array(
     'choices' => array('foo' => 'Foo', 'bar' => 'Bar', 'baz' => 'Baz'),
     'preferred_choices' => array('baz'),
));
```

Comment: That won't work, seeing as the OP wants to render an _entity_ as a choice field. Considering the data is an entity, you'll want to map the values onto the entity, too...